# Read After Write(RAW) hazard

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-pipelines

I am confused in finding RAW dependencies whether we have to find only in adjacent instructions or non-adjacent also.

consider the following assembly code

I1: ADD R1 , R2, R2;

I2: ADD R3, R2, R1;

I3: SUB R4, R1 , R5;

I4: ADD R3, R3, R4;

FIND THE NUMBER OF READ AFTER WRITE(RAW) DEPENDENCIES IN THE Above Code.

I am getting 2 dependency  I2-I1 and I4-I3.

Comment: I'd say it includes non-adjacent instructions. For example, in a 5-levels pipeline (F-D-E-M-W), there is 2 cycles between exectution and registers updates.

Answer (score 1):

Adjacency is not relevant for determining Read-After-Write dependences.  You simply list *all* the instructions where one of the source registers reads the value produced by some previous instruction.

So (assuming that your assembly language is `OPERATOR DEST SRC1 SRC2`) you are missing, for example, that the first source operand of `I3` dependends on the value written by `I1`.  (You are missing several others as well.)